# Jenkins Failed to run AVD creation command

Tags: android, jenkins, amazon-ec2, android-virtual-device

I installed jenkins using bitnami on an ec2 instance.  Logged in, installed android plugin and created an emulator image. When I try to run the build, following error appears, There doesn't seem to be anything special in my setup besides this being on ec2 instead of running on a local server, any ideas what I am doing wrong?  It did download the sdk and the files all seem to be in the right place, not sure if I'm missing some permission or forgot to do a step. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Started by user User Name
Building in workspace /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/rChery/workspace
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/***/**.git
Checking out Revision 096d855de760e2f7b95a548cf0ff0e065c10c704 (origin/master)
/opt/bitnami/git/bin/git: 2: /opt/bitnami/scripts/setenv.sh: egrep: not found
$ /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/tools/android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk
[android] Creating Android AVD: /.android/avd/hudson_en-US_240_WXGA720_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_19_armeabi-v7a.avd
[android] /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/tools/android create avd -f -a -s WXGA720 -n hudson_en-US_240_WXGA720_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_19_armeabi-v7a -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19" --abi armeabi-v7a
[android] Could not create Android emulator: Failed to run AVD creation command
Build did not succeed and the project is configured to only push after a successful build, so no pushing will occur.
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

Comment: running into the same problem. it seems to be that jenkins running as a service cannot access sdk tools or something like that, im looking into this as well and found this closed ticket. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9623

Comment: id also check the console output where jenkins is calling the sdk tools from, i noticed mine ill try and fix mine and hopefully be able to post an answer at the end of the day